# Saving Files to Google Drive

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-drive-api

I want to develop a php app which will allow users to upload their files to a common google drive.

Is it possible to do it using the google drive api without user login. i.e the app should make the authentication to the common account.

Comment: Be sure you want to do this because you get inefficient traffic. All requests (uploading/downloading) must go trough your domain. Uploading for example will take twice the time. Uploading a file first to your domain and after that you have to move/upload the file to the google domain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you set up a common Drive account and use Drive API such as [Files.insert()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert), you can let user upload file without login. Actually, there is a [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php) for php which does almost same thing for you. You may want to start from this quickstart to upload a file from your server to Drive and integrate it with form to let any users upload file to your Drive.

Comment: I have tried that Quickstart. It require the user to allow access to the drive every time the file is being uploaded and the user needs to be logged in. in this case if its on some other computer then its gets saved in the drive of the user logged in on that machine.

Comment: You need to fix quickstart code to make it do what you want. To make it not ask you for log in everytime, you need to save credentials and load it. Check this documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/training/drive-apps/auth/credentials There are some samples with php, too

Comment: I am Saving all the credentials. When i tried to run the code when some other user was logged in. the file got uploaded to that users drive.

Comment: the correct url of the quick start is [https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php)